# How to calculate a point horizontaly projected to an angled line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, linear-algebra

[image]

We are using Unity C#. This image is a simplified 2D situation, in which we know the coordinates (x,y) of points **p1** and **p2**.

We know the angle Theta, using this beauty

```cs
static float CalculateAngle(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
{ return Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.right, p1 - p2).eulerAngles.z; }

// The use of Vector3.right make zero degrees start at 3h00
// The values of z are irrelevant in this post, always zeroed.
```

Now a new point **p3** shows up, imagine a screen touch, so we know it's coordinates (x,y). In essence, everything **blue** in the image, we know it's values.

The question is this: how to calculate a new **p4** coordinates, in which

- **we know** p3(x,y) coordinates
- **we don't know** p4(x,y), except that:
- p4.y **has to be equal** to p3.y
- p4 is **in line** with p1 and p2

How to calculate the unknown p4.x, to have the full p4(x,y) coordinates, using Unity C#?

Comment: is it always going to be a 2d situation & horizontal projection?

Comment: Ah, missed this comment, yes 2D scenario, only using Vector3(x, y, z) float values, z is irrelevant, actually being forced zero before and after calculations. Projection is always horizontal, x axis, coming from both sides left and right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be easier solutions out there. The basic Math solution is as follows:

1. Calculate the linear function of p1 and p2 as mentioned [here](https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-1/formulating-linear-equations/writing-linear-equations-using-the-slope-intercept-form). An equation in the slope-intercept form is written as

> y = mx + b

where m is the slope of the line and b is the y-intercept.

3. Insert P3's y into the form.
4. Solve x.

**Example in C# for Unity:**

```
Vector3 p1 = new Vector3(1f, 2f);
Vector3 p2 = new Vector3(2f, 3f);
Vector3 p3 = new Vector3(1000f, 5f);
Vector3 p4 = Vector3.zero;

float m = ((p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x));
float b = p1.y - (m * p1.x);

// x = ( y - b ) / m
p4.x = (p3.y - b) / m;
p4.y = p3.y;

print(p4); // (4.0, 5.0, 0.0) as expected
```

Comment: Hey Fabian, I clarified my post a bit, I'm right now testing your idea, and getting some extreme x values... will reply you later, when I get to a conclusion. Thanks.

Comment: If using your example values, for an easy 45º angle, p1(1,2), p2(2,3), and a rogue p3(100, 5), then p4 should be **(4,5)** and **not (6,5)** as you said to be expected in this scenario. Running your code with this values, does indeed return (6,5) but the correct coordinates would be (4,5). All values are treated like floats. Something is wrong. Would love to see a sexy math formula like this working on the fly yes.

Comment: @Marco António: thanks for your feedback, I will have a look at it tomorrow. ;-)

Comment: Found the glitch in your code, and now is running perfectly! You wrote the line "float n = m * p1.x - p1.y;" but it's actually "float b = p1.y - (m * p1.x);". I'll edit your code, and mark it solved. Thanks Fabian.

Comment: Well done and thanks! Apologies for not testing it more thoroughly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Linear functions are of the form y = mx + b, where m is the slope and b is the vertical shift. If P3 is a point with an xy values, then you can take the slope, the offset, and y and solve for x:

```
(y - b) / m = x
```

This is more of a general math question than a unity specific question; in the future, I'd suggest trying the stack exchange math site.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, and it also works for `p1`,`p2`, and/or `p3` with different depths:

Create a plane where `Y=p3.y`, and then raycast from p1->p2 to find where it intersects.

```
Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, p3);
float enter;
Ray ray = new Ray(p1, p2-p1);

bool doesIntersect = plane.Raycast(ray, out enter);
if (doesIntersect) {
    Vector3 p4 = ray.GetPoint(enter); 
    DoStuff(p4.x); 
}
```

If you need to project along a non-horizontal direction, you'll need to use a different normal than `Vector3.up`.